# Heroku Resque Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out

Tags: heroku, redis, resque, redistogo

We have a Heroku app configured with Redis To Go (Small) running a few Resque workers. Recently we've noticed lots of errors in Airbrake saying "Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out" (see screenshot below). We're not anywhere near our connection limit of 256 Redis connections or our data limit of 100MB. Looking at the backtraces of these exceptions, it seems they can happen anywhere the Resque code tries to make calls to Redis. There's not one specific line of code that leads to this error, though eventually all the backtraces reach this line of code, which raises the TimeoutError:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:198:in `rescue in io'
```

Any ideas?

[image: Airbrake errors]

Comment: We contacted Redis To Go about this issue and they made some change on their end to make the connections more reliable and it seemed to resolve the issue.